# Facebook connect alike service design practices

Tags: php, javascript

There several threads on SO regarding this, but I just need to know how to READ a cookie from siteb.com on sitea.com that opens siteb.com on a iframe, **IF** this is really the recommended way to go.

Based on [this](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/08/how-facebook-sets-and-uses-cross-domain-cookies/) post the author says:

> Cookies can be read in an iframe if they were set outside of the
>   iframe

But I have no idea how to achieve this. Let me explain a bit more about what im trying to design so maybe you can point me in the right direction.

siteb.com is my website, where users login and signup, each time they do, a cookie is set like many normal authentication systems.

sitea.com is a generic site, where I can insert html and javascript code, from sitea I need -if exists- to read the login cookie of siteb. I think an iframe on sitea loading siteb will do the trick, but again, i have no idea how to access that cookies inside the iframe. Is there an easy way to do this?

Another approach i was thinking is to use cross domain iframe communication techniques, but they are not elegant, way complex and some of them fails in certain browsers, the most robust ones uses jquery but I don't want to insert jquery on sitea.

Comment: Cookies can't be shared across domains like that. They can be shared across sub-domains.  If you are really trying to do some sort of cross-domain logins, you should perhaps investigate OAuth or something less archaic than some hacked up iframe technique.

Comment: I dont want to do a cross domain login system, what I need is way more simple, I just need to know if the user is logged on siteb from sitaa, so if the cookie is set, just that,

Comment: also, way the article said that I can read cookies inside an iframe if they were set outsite of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need: http://easyxdm.net/ - load this library on both sitea.com and the siteb.com iframe. It makes cross-domain parent-iframe communication "just work" in every browser, using the fastest method avaliable in each browser. (Also, the author, https://stackoverflow.com/users/128035/sean-kinsey does a fantastic job of helping anyone who has trouble with the library - just check the mailing list archives)

Then add a tiny bit of JavaScript to your siteb.com iframe to read cookies and pass them to easyxdm and then add a bit of JavaScript to sitea.com to set up easyxdm (including creating the iframe, I think) and receive the cookie value from it. There's lots of examples on the website to help you get started.